# Push View Controller from app delegate in tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Im trying to display a ViewController, from my openURL function inside my AppDelegate class, but im not having any luck. Ive tried every solution i could find on the internet, im not sure what im doing wrong... please note i have a tabbed application..

I dont really want to use `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex` because I really want to display a custom built controller like so:

```
CategoryTableViewController *controller = nil;
NSUInteger catId = 6;
NSString *title = @"Cat Title!";
NSManagedObjectContext *inMemoryContext = [xyzclient newContextUsingInMemoryStore:YES];
controller = [[CategoryTableViewController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:inMemoryContext];
[(CategoryTableViewController *) controller setParentCategory:catId];
[(CategoryTableViewController *) controller setFilterCategory:NO];
[(CategoryTableViewController *) controller setStopRefresh:YES];
controller.title = title;
[self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Here is the code ive written:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSString *scheme = [url scheme];

    if ([scheme hasPrefix:@"xyz"]) {
        //Attempt 1
        UINavigationController *searchNavigationController = [self navigationControllerForViewControllerClass:[SearchTableViewController class]];
        [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController pushViewController:searchNavigationController animated:YES];

        //Attempt 2

        NSManagedObjectContext *inMemoryContext = [DealsClient newContextUsingInMemoryStore:YES];
        SearchTableViewController *controller = [[SearchTableViewController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:inMemoryContext];
        [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
     }
}

- (UINavigationController *)navigationControllerForViewControllerClass:(Class)viewControllerClass {
    BaseViewController *viewController = [[viewControllerClass alloc] init];
    viewController.context = [self managedObjectContext];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BaseNavigationController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewController];

    return navigationController;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [DClient setBaseManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    UINavigationController *featuredNavigationController = [self navigationControllerForViewControllerClass:[FeaturedTableViewController class]];
    featuredNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Home", nil) image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_home"] tag:TabBarTabHome];
    UINavigationController *browseNavigationController = [self navigationControllerForViewControllerClass:[CategoryTableViewController class]];
    browseNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Browse", nil) image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_browse"] tag:TabBarTabBrowse];
    UINavigationController *searchNavigationController = [self navigationControllerForViewControllerClass:[SearchTableViewController class]];
    searchNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Search", nil) image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_search"] tag:TabBarTabSearch];
    UINavigationController *messagesNavigationController = [self navigationControllerForViewControllerClass:[MessagesTableViewController class]];
    messagesNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Messages", nil) image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_messages"] tag:TabBarTabMessages];
    UINavigationController *cartNavigationController = [self navigationControllerForViewControllerClass:[CartTableViewController class]];
    cartNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cart", nil) image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_cart"] tag:TabBarTabCart];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:featuredNavigationController, browseNavigationController, searchNavigationController, messagesNavigationController, cartNavigationController, nil];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];

    [xyzEngine setTabBarController:self.tabBarController];

    [self.tabBarController setCartBadgeValue:[xyz numItemsInCart]];
    NSLog(@"Loaded the page....");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: From what I see you're trying to push a navigation controller into another navigation controller embedded in your tab bar controller. I imagine that's not what you want, is it?

Comment: i tired pushing the controller as well.. but it didnt work, ive made an edit (see attempt 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm still not entirely sure of what you're trying to achieve exactly so I'm gonna assume the following:

You have a tab bar controller with 5 items. Each item is a navigation controller that has a specific class. Based on the url parameter passed to `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` you want to select the proper item (which was already been loaded previously in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) of your tab bar controller .

Here's my attempt:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    if ([scheme hasPrefix:@"xyz"]) {
        Class navigationControllerClass = [SearchTableViewController class];

        NSUInteger navigationControllerIndex = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
          BOOL found = [obj isKindOfClass:navigationControllerClass];
          if (found) {
            *stop = YES;
          }
          return found;
        }];

        if (NSNotFound != navigationControllerIndex) {
            self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = navigationControllerIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Take 2

In your 2 attempts you're creating a new *navigation* controller and then try to push it on something that's `nil` (`self.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController` is `nil` since `self.tabBarController.selectedViewController` is a navigation controller).

Whatever you're pushing in your navigation controller cannot be another navigation controller. So you need to create a simple view controller of type `UIViewController` and push it to the currently selected navigation controller of your tab bar.

```
if ([scheme hasPrefix:@"xyz"]) {
    MYViewController *controller = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:inMemoryContext];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thx mate, everything you said is right... but.. Is there anyway i can display my own `created` viewcontroller, please see my question edited..

Comment: Do you want to display a newly created *navigation* controller in your tab bar (basically add a 6th item)? or do you want to push a newly created *view* controller in an existing navigation controller (being an item of the tab bar)?

Comment: i think `push a newly created view controller in an existing navigation controller`... please see the code ive just added in the question